# Testing for the linear independence of the rows/columns of rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Am I right that the rows of an $(n-1)\times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{A}_{(n-1)\times n}$, are linearly dependent iff
$$A_{n,i}=0,\forall i\in\{1,..,n\}\text{, where }A_{n,i}\text{ is the }(n,i)\text{-th cofactor of }\mathbf{A}_{n\times n},$$

where $\mathbf{A}_{n\times n}$ is $\mathbf{A}_{(n-1)\times n}$ with a blank row added to its bottom? If so, how does one prove it?

Comment: Not very good to denote the matrix and the cofactor with the same symbol $A$.

Comment: If the matrix has $m$ rows, what's the cofactor relative to $(m+1,i)$?

Comment: You've got a point: I hadn't thought about the general case, only the $(n-1)\times n$ matrix case. In hindsight, I was wrong in calling these cofactors: it should be corrected to read, "the determinants of every possible combination of $m$ of the $n$ columns of the matrix are zero."

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the more general case of $m\times n$ matrices, $\mathbf{A}_{m\times n}$, with $m<n$, where we posit that the $m$ rows of such a matrix are linearly dependent iff the determinants of all $n\choose m$ of its $m\times m$ submatrices are zero.

If the $m$ rows are linearly dependent, it is easy to show that the columns must also be linearly dependent, so that any $m\times m$ submatrix made up of $m$ of the $n$ columns must also have linearly dependent rows. Thus, their determinants must all be zero. This proves that if the rows of $\mathbf{A}_{m\times n}$ are linearly dependent, all of these determinants must be zero; if any of them is not, they are independent, the only other possible outcome. There remains to prove the converse: if all these determinants are zero, the rows of the matrix are linearly dependent.

But, is there an easier test?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting to prove that an $m\times n$ matrix with $m<n$ has rank less than $m$ (that is, linearly dependent rows) if and only if the determinant of every submatrix obtained by removing $n-m$ columns is $0$.

Suppose the rank is less than $m$. Then one row, say the $i$-th, is a linear combination of the other $m-1$ rows. Then if you remove $n-m$ columns, the $i$-th row in the submatrix is still a linear combination of the other rows, so the determinant is $0$.

Conversely, suppose that the rank is $m$. Then the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has $m$ pivot columns; the columns of the matrix $A$ corresponding to them are linearly independent, so the determinant of the submatrix obtained by removing the non pivot columns is $\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you for that, egreg, but somehow I'm not seeing that you've shown the converse of "the rank is $<m$ implies the determinants are zero," which would be "all these determinants are zero implies that the rank is $<m$."

Comment: In fact, egreg, in your last paragraph, you've shown the contrapositive of what you've shown in your second paragraph.

Comment: @JeremyRiley Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. To answer

Comment: To answer my other question, Gaussian elimination to row-echelon form may be an easier method to determine independence if $m$ is small compared to $n$, and it also has the added benefit of determining the rank, from the count of the pivot columns.

Comment: @JeremyRiley Certainly so: *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the converse, let's prove its contrapositive (the inverse): linear independence of the rows implies all the determinants cannot be zero.

Using the definition of linear independence, we can show that, for any matrix, square or rectangular, the number of independent rows equals the number of independent columns; that number is the rank. If the $m$ rows are linearly independent, then there must be exactly as many independent columns that form a basis for the columns. Thus, there must be at least one set of $m$ columns whose determinant is non-zero (QED).